# Should I delete my question or give someone credit for enlightening me?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, english

I made a question with a bad English translation. I meant highlight... And I said blur. It is still a legitimate question, but...

Someone finally understood while discussing in comments and did provide the answer needed. It would have been a correct question if written correctly from the beginning. I feel a bit bad because a good translation solves about half of the question.

*[Select (highlight) content of TextBox on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992151/blur-textbox-content-when-clicked/52992807?noredirect=1#comment92891266_52992807)*

Now I see three options:

1. Delete and remake question.
2. Change question title, then accept the answer that solves the actual problem.
3. Ask here.

Comment: Interesting dilemma. I wouldn't suggest deleting it, fixing it will invalidate two of the three answers, maybe just leave it as is?

Comment: @KevinB With a title that doesn't reflect the actual question ? And i would accept an answer even so ? I don't mind but...

Comment: You don't necessarily have to accept an answer either.... but i'd suggest accepting the one that solved your problem.

Comment: Well, I like the idea of accepting the answer, let's start by doing this.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much point to that.  When you understand what blur *really* means then you don't have a question anymore.  The answerers guessed correctly, so problem solved.

Comment: @Antoine since you're saying poor translation I'll assume from French... Which makes me curious as to what the translation was to begin with? I don't see how blur and highlight can translate to the same (or similar) French.. you got me curious lol

Comment: @Patrice Yeah lol... I can't tell you exactly why, but Blur sounded to me like "adding blue color over something" and thus, the action of highlighting text...

Comment: Google trad sais that "Blur" = "Brouiller" which is not so far away from highlighting and way away from what blur does mean in JQuery or Javascript

Comment: Does [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/blur) translates it better?

Comment: @brasofilo This seems better yes. In any case, the problem is more HOW javascript decided to use the word blur as a function, for loosing focus on a control rather than actually making a visual effect on it.

Comment: For what it's worth: the first thing you should do when a built-in or library function doesn't do what you think it should is to look up its documentation, which should pretty quickly tell you that you're expecting the wrong thing. Although I'm not sure you'd have been able to figure out what the *right* function to use is by doing that.

Comment: You have a question as stated and a question as intended. So here's option 4: Add a new first paragraph and mention the duality there, making sure to include good titles for both questions as sentences. That serves SO's primary audience (people who google for solutions to problems) for both problems while being honest with everyone who answered.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier to be fair to JavaScript - it's not its fault. It's [part of the DOM specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-blur) not really part of JS. Although that just changes your question to "why 'blur' was chosen as an event type by the HTML specification people" and I can't really say. I guess I can see some rationale because it's the "blur" (in the meaning of "moment of time") when focus is lost from one element and given to another. Although I'm not sure if that's the intended meaning and even if it is, it's a bit stretched. Could have been called "focus shift".

Comment: I assume "blur" was chosen just because it's the opposite of "focus."

Comment: This sounds more like a word you'd use as a photographe. In any case, now I know...But I won't edit the question myself. I'm afraid of making it even worst...